# Tweet button parameters: What does the 'related' parameter do?

Tags: twitter, tweets

According to the official [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters), the `related` parameter is:

> A comma-separated list of accounts related to the content of the shared URI.

**But what exactly does it do?** When the tweet is sent, the added twitter accounts are never included within the tweet message. And they do not receive a notification either about the tweet.

Comment: Since there is no information about this anywhere on the web, I will bounty this question with 50 points when it is eligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only see the related accounts *after* you've interacted with the tweet button.

> Suggest additional Twitter usernames related to the Tweet as comma-separated values. Twitter may suggest these accounts to follow after the user posts their Tweet. You may provide a brief description of how the account relates to the Tweet with a URL-encoded comma and text after the username.
>
> https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

User hits the button, user posts tweet, user sees the accounts you added in the `related` field.

Comment: Do you work for Twitter? That snippet of information is buried in the web. ;)